# wget - if requested file is 0kb or connection timed out then do not save file

Tags: wget

I have a script to download file from a siemens PLC and save with date.

```
 set _my_datetime=%date%_%time%
 set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime: =_%
 set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime::=_%
 set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:/=_%
 set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:.=_%
 set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:,=_%

c:\Progra~2\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe -t 5 --referer=http://192.yyy.xx.102/Portal/Portal.mwsl?PriNav=FileBrowser  http://192.yyy.xx.102/FileBrowser/Download?Path=/DataLogs/Datalog_Yazaki.csv^&RAW --output-document=F:\DataLog_%_my_datetime%.csv --delete-after
```

And it makes lot of 0kb file if the plc not running.

How do i modify the script to check if it is "0kb" or "no connection" to host then do not save file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved with a script on linux which is deleting 0kb files.

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -size 0 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you do `wget` try to check the ERRORLEVEL.If its not zero then most probably the command errored out.

```
set _my_datetime=%date%_%time%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime: =_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime::=_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:/=_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:.=_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:,=_%

c:\Progra~2\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe -t 5 --referer=http://192.yyy.xx.102/Portal/Portal.mwsl?PriNav=FileBrowser  http://192.yyy.xx.102/FileBrowser/Download?Path=/DataLogs/Datalog_Yazaki.csv^&RAW --output-document=C:\DataLog_%_my_datetime%.csv --delete-after

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo "Error occurred"
  GOTO END
)

:END
REM Exit routine
```

Comment: Dear Rambler, I would like to ask  you  to update my code? I dont know where i have to insert your code correctly.

Comment: i thought the same but it doesn't work. It is in a batch file . it have to be an other syntax?

Comment: It still create 0kb file .

Comment: i think it will be solve this problem from server side in linux. check and delete all 0 byte files

Comment: Also checkout this link for wget error codes , they might help you in pinpointing the exact error code : https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: Dear Rambler, Thank you for your help.I tried all error codes but not works. The auto delete zero byte files solution works well.

Comment: Oh! Great then! :)